# Apache POI Workbook don't read file (Java Android)

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

I trying read xlsx file from external storage.

I downloaded .jar file from web to ApachePOI, the version is poi-5.2.2.jar and implement library on gradle (implementation files('libs\poi-5.2.2.jar'). The next step was this code:

```
try {

        File file = new File(root.getContext().getExternalFilesDir(null), "contacts.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);

        // Fetch first sheet (index: 0)
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(root.getContext(), "error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

When i play this code show a fatal error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.martin.preventapp, PID: 3630
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager;
```

and reference this line:

```
Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
```

I tryed with many tutorials but the error is every equal. What's the problem here??

Comment: "I downloaded .jar file from web to ApachePOI" -- you probably need other libraries. It would be easier to find the Maven coordinates for a hosted copy of the library, as that will pull in additional libraries ("transitive dependencies") as needed. For example, using `implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.2'` should work better than `implementation files('libs\poi-5.2.2.jar')`.

Comment: CommonsWare, thanks for reply, i added all dependencies what show on apache poi web and work fine. i thinked what poi-5.2.2.jar contained all. thanks again!!!!

Comment: Could you share please what implementations you are using after you solved your problem ? And if you are using the jars or not, it will help, thanks.